# How to remove a specific row of JScrollPane?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jscrollpane

I'm using [JScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) what I'm trying to do is remove a specific row from the panel. Actually in the documentation I found nothing about this. A bit example:

**JScrollPane Data Structure**

```
<div id="services_added">
    <div class="services_added-row" data-id="1">
          <strong>Taglio capelli</strong>
          <br>Durata: 20 - Prezzo: 50.00 €<br>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="services_added-row" data-id="2">
          <strong>Colore capelli</strong>
          <br>Durata: 50 - Prezzo: 30.00 €<br>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

How I can remove the `data-id=2`? Actually I intercept the row clicked by this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.services_added-row', function()
{
     var serviceId = $(this).attr('data-id');
});
```

Also, I want to remove the `hr` tag before the row too.

Comment: Do you want to remove the clicked row?

Comment: Yes, the clicked row is part of the JScrollPane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to remove the `div` you just clicked on it. Right? If so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.services_added-row', function() {
 $(this).remove();
});
```

**Update**

If you want to remove the previews `hr` tag you can do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.services_added-row', function() {
 var elem = $(this);
 elem.prev().remove();
 elem.remove();
});
```

(There are a lot of options to do this, but this way is the most easy to understand)

Comment: Okay seems working, but the tag <hr> still remain in the JScrollPane